# How to have abovedisplayshortskip and belowdisplayskip at the same time

Tags: spacing, belowdisplayskip

Does somebody know how to have a normal *belowdisplayskip* when the *abovedisplayshortskip* is triggered?
To clarify take a look at this code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,float}


\begin{document}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1em}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{1em}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0em}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0em}

tale lavoro è uguale al lavoro virtuale esterno che sappiamo essere nullo, possiamo quindi scrivere
\begin{equation*}
    X=-\frac{\int_0^LM^aM^0dz}{\int_0^L(M^a)^2dz}
\end{equation*}
sostituiamo i valori dei momenti flettenti e risolviamo gli integrali
\end{document}
```

which gives this output:
[image]
You can notice that a *abovedisplayshortskip* is triggered because the upper line is short enough. On the other hand the bottom line is long so a *belowdisplayskip* should be triggered, however a *belowdisplayshortskip* is triggered as you can notice in the example.

Waiting for your answers geniuses! ^-^

Comment: Shouldn't it be *genii* ? ; –)

Comment: It'll change if you became my guide by giving the correct answer :P

Comment: I don't have time to test at the moment, but I remember having noted once that with the `\useshortskip` (from `nccmath`), \abovedisplayskip is indeed shortened, but not \belowdisplayskip. Maybe it would yield a solution to your problem?

Comment: Does not seem to work

Comment: don't you just want `\belowdisplayshortskip=\displayshortskip` ?

Comment: you misunderstand the intent of `\belowdisplayshortskip` it is not intended to be conditional based on the the length of the following line, it is conditional depending on whether `\abovedisplayshortskip` was used. That is `the bottom line is long so a belowdisplayskip should be triggered` is not the test that is intended here.

Comment: I think it's "safe" to set `\belowdisplayshortskip` to the length of `\belowdisplayskip` and change it locally only when it's needed. The first lines of paragraphs are usually long enough.

Answer (score 1):

How does TeX choose between the normal skips or the ‘short’ ones? It's simple: if the line *preceding* the display is short (according to some hardwired logic), the ‘short’ version are employed above and below, otherwise the ‘normal’ ones.

The line below the display is generally *not short*. OK, there are cases in which it might be, but that's *not* looked at by TeX. Never.

Setting `\belowdisplayshortskip` to zero is always wrong. Let's see what plain TeX does:

```
\abovedisplayskip=12pt plus 3pt minus 9pt
\abovedisplayshortskip=0pt plus 3pt
\belowdisplayskip=12pt plus 3pt minus 9pt
\belowdisplayshortskip=7pt plus 3pt minus 4pt
```

Some flexibility is always added, in order to help with pagination. The same choice is done by the LaTeX kernel. The AMS classes use a different method and set the skips depending on the font size. At 10 pt we have the equivalent of

```
\abovedisplayskip=4.2pt plus 4.2pt
\abovedisplayshortskip=0pt plus 4.2pt
\belowdisplayskip=4.2pt plus 4.2pt
\belowdisplayshortskip=2.1pt plus 4.2pt
```

so generally the skips are smaller than in the standard LaTeX classes, so no shrinkability is set. Actually it's not `4.2pt`, but `4.19998pt`, but the difference is just 1 scaled point.

***Never*** set `\belowdisplayshortskip` to zero. That's all. If the line below the display turns out to be short and you get an unsightly gap, you can, in the very final stage of production, add

```
\vadjust pre {\vskip-\belowdisplayskip}
```

in the line.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\[
a+b=c
\]
and that's all.

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\[
a+b=c
\]
and that's all.\vadjust pre {\vskip-\belowdisplayskip}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value of `\belowdisplayshortskip` within a group, as in the second example underneath:

```
    \documentclass[twoside]{report}
    \usepackage{amsmath,float}

    \begin{document}

    \allowdisplaybreaks
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1em}
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{1em}
    \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0em}
    \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0em}

    tale lavoro è uguale al lavoro virtuale esterno che sappiamo essere nullo, possiamo quindi scrivere
    \begin{equation*}
        X=-\frac{\int_0^LM^aM^0dz}{\int_0^L(M^a)^2dz}
    \end{equation*}
    sostituiamo i valori dei momenti flettenti e risolviamo gli integrali \vskip2em


    {\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{1em}
    tale lavoro è uguale al lavoro virtuale esterno che sappiamo essere nullo, possiamo quindi scrivere
    \begin{equation*}
        X=-\frac{\int_0^LM^aM^0dz}{\int_0^L(M^a)^2dz}
    \end{equation*}
    sostituiamo i valori dei momenti flettenti e risolviamo gli integrali}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does not exist a global solution to fix this error? Why Latek do not use the *belowdisplayskip* as it should?

Comment: Personally, I don't know one. But maybe some TeX guru (which I'm not) will have a solution.

Comment: @ahahfilip what error do you see?

Comment: After the equation the line is long, so there should be a space assigned by \belowdisplayskip, and not by \belowdisplayshortskip

Comment: @ahahfilip No. The line after the equation is not considered (and is not available at that point) . belowdisplayshortskip is used if aboveshortdisplayshortskip is used.

Comment: While understanding the explanation about `belowdisplayshortskip` and when it is triggered, it also makes little sense to me that `belowdisplayshortskip` is triggered by `abovedisplayshortskip`.  The latter is controlled by the length of a line "above" the equation. Logically, I'd expect `belowdisplayshortskip` would be controlled by the line "below" the equation.

Comment: @Celdor Your expectation is wrong. The idea is that the line below an equation is usually long. If the line *preceding* the display is short, the `short` skips are used to avoid a big gap above an an overall unbalanced appearance. `\belowdisplayshortskip` should *never* be set to zero.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. It makes more sense what LaTeX does after looking at examples (yours in the answer and a few more I have made).